# IPC MSG Queue how to identify message type of each message that is sent?

Tags: c, ipc, message-queue, message-type

I just learned about MSG queues and I tried to write two processes with common keys, where one sends messages and another reads messages then removes the queue. But the problem is, I want to know which message had which type when they're sent.

**Here is my console results:**

> MSG sent: MSG_6
> MSG sent: MSG_2
> MSG sent: MSG_8
> MSG sent: MSG_9
> MSG sent: MSG_8
> MSG sent: MSG_3
> MSG sent: MSG_6
> MSG sent: MSG_6
> MSG sent: MSG_2
> MSG sent: MSG_5
> Recieved type: 5, MSG_6
> Recieved type: 5, MSG_2
> Recieved type: 5, MSG_8
> Recieved type: 5, MSG_9
> Recieved type: 5, MSG_8
> Recieved type: 5, MSG_3
> Recieved type: 5, MSG_6
> Recieved type: 5, MSG_6
> Recieved type: 5, MSG_2
> Recieved type: 5, MSG_5
> Now removing the QEUE in 3 seconds

I was expecting that mtype would be same as each MSG sent. However, as you can see receiver process only prints very last MSG type. If I'm able to get each MSG types so that I can sort them in a some way.

**IPC_COMMON.h** where both sender and receiver includes this header file.

> 

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define TEST_ERROR    if (errno) {fprintf(stderr, \
                      "%s:%d: PID=%5d: Error %d (%s)\n", \
                      __FILE__,         \
                      __LINE__,         \
                      getpid(),         \
                      errno,            \
                      strerror(errno));}
#define MSG_LEN 120

struct msgbuf {
    long mtype;
    char mtext[MSG_LEN];
};

#define MY_KEY 0x123456
#define MSGTYPE_RM  7
```

**SENDER.c**

> 

```
#include "testCommon.h"
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    int id_q;
    struct msgbuf my_msg;
    int typeArr[10];
    int i;
    
    id_q = msgget(MY_KEY, IPC_CREAT | 0600);
    TEST_ERROR;
    
    srand(time(NULL));
        
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        typeArr[i] = rand() % 10;
        my_msg.mtype = typeArr[i];
        printf("Printing types %d\n", typeArr[i]);      
    }
    
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        switch(typeArr[i]) {
        case 0:
            strcpy(my_msg.mtext , "MSG_0");
            msgsnd(id_q, &my_msg, MSG_LEN, 0);
            printf("MSG sent: %s\n", my_msg.mtext);
            break;
        case 1:
            strcpy(my_msg.mtext , "MSG_1");
            msgsnd(id_q, &my_msg, MSG_LEN, 0);
            printf("MSG sent: %s\n", my_msg.mtext);
            break;
        case 2:
            strcpy(my_msg.mtext , "MSG_2");
            msgsnd(id_q, &my_msg, MSG_LEN, 0);
            printf("MSG sent: %s\n", my_msg.mtext);
            break;
        case 3:
            strcpy(my_msg.mtext , "MSG_3");
            msgsnd(id_q, &my_msg, MSG_LEN, 0);
            printf("MSG sent: %s\n", my_msg.mtext);
            break;
        case 4:
            strcpy(my_msg.mtext , "MSG_4");
            msgsnd(id_q, &my_msg, MSG_LEN, 0);
            printf("MSG sent: %s\n", my_msg.mtext);
            break;
        case 5:
            strcpy(my_msg.mtext , "MSG_5");
            msgsnd(id_q, &my_msg, MSG_LEN, 0);
            printf("MSG sent: %s\n", my_msg.mtext);
            break;
        case 6:
            strcpy(my_msg.mtext , "MSG_6");
            msgsnd(id_q, &my_msg, MSG_LEN, 0);
            printf("MSG sent: %s\n", my_msg.mtext);
            break;
        case 7:
            strcpy(my_msg.mtext , "MSG_7");
            msgsnd(id_q, &my_msg, MSG_LEN, 0);
            printf("MSG sent: %s\n", my_msg.mtext);
            break;
        case 8:
            strcpy(my_msg.mtext , "MSG_8");
            msgsnd(id_q, &my_msg, MSG_LEN, 0);
            printf("MSG sent: %s\n", my_msg.mtext);
            break;
        case 9:
            strcpy(my_msg.mtext , "MSG_9");
            msgsnd(id_q, &my_msg, MSG_LEN, 0);
            printf("MSG sent: %s\n", my_msg.mtext);
            break;
        default:
            fprintf(stderr, "Error occurred\n.");
            TEST_ERROR;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**RECEIVER.c**

> 

```
#include "testCommon.h"

int main() {
    int q_id, num_bytes, i;
    struct msgbuf my_msg;
    num_bytes = 0;
    q_id = msgget(MY_KEY, IPC_CREAT | 0600);
    TEST_ERROR;
    
    while (1) {
        /* now receiving the message */
            for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            num_bytes += msgrcv(q_id, &my_msg, MSG_LEN, 0, 0);
            printf("Recieved type: %ld, %s \n", my_msg.mtype, my_msg.mtext);
            }   
            if(num_bytes >= 0)
            break;  
    }
    printf("Now removing the QEUE in 3 seconds\n");
    sleep(3);
    msgctl(q_id, IPC_RMID, NULL);       
}
```

Comment: "*as you can see receiver process only prints very last MSG type*" -- no, I can't see that, because I choose not to load or try to read your images.  Do not post images of text.  Rather, copy & paste the text *as* text.  Use code-block formatting for it to avoid line breaks and similar being mangled.

Comment: You post a header that you label as `IPC_COMMON.h`.  Is this the same thing that the two programs reference as `testCommon.h`?

Comment: Do not test `errno` to try to determine whether an error has occurred.  This can produce both false positives and false negatives.  Functions that can fail provide direct means to detect that, generally in the form of special return values.  Checking those is how you must determine whether an error occurred.  *Some*, but not all, functions use `errno` to convey the nature of such failures.  Consult `errno` for that information only (immediately) after a function indicates that it failed.

Comment: Message types must be strictly greater than 0.  Your test code affords the possibility that some of those you use are 0.

Comment: thank you for your answer and comments, sorry about the picture tho, you seem irritated. I'll keep that mind from now on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was expecting that mtype would be same as each MSG sent.

There are a few issues with your code, which I have mostly raised in comments on the question.  But the *main* issue appears to be that you set `my_msg.mtype` for the last time before you send any messages to the queue.  You set the `mtext` data each time, but not `mtype`.  I would expect, then, that all the messages come across with the message type designated in the sender by `typeArr[9]`, as that's the last `mtype` value you set.

You might try this instead of the sender's two `for` loops:

```
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        my_msg.mtype = 1 + rand() % 9;
        sprintf(my_msg.mtext, "MSG_%ld", my_msg.mtype);
        ssize_t result = msgsnd(id_q, &my_msg, MSG_LEN, 0);
        if (result == -1) {
            // handle error ...
        } else {
            printf("MSG type %ld sent: %s\n", my_msg.mtype, my_msg.mtext);
        }
    }
```